# PHP file_get_contents() is extremely slow

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, file-get-contents

I've been working on a certain code for a while. I've noticed the execution time of the code is about 10-13 seconds - which is very slow.

Therefore, I've decided to figure out which function makes the execution time so slow, and I've figured out the only `file_get_contents($url)` is running for 9 seconds. The `$url` is Facebook graph API data.

A suggestion in another message on Stackoverflow suggested using

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close')));
$content = file_get_contents($dataUrl,false,$context);
```

I've also tried this, and it didn't improve the run time at all. Is there any way to pull the data which won't last so long?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Tried using cURL , it takes about 7-8 seconds , which is still a lot , what am I able to do ? I'm running the code on localhsot , xampp, apache , does it matter?

Comment: How much data are you fetching? is it limitation of the data-serving-server?

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use [CURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Also, If you are starting many connections in a loop, CURL can start them all at once. Otherwise, it shouldn't take that long.

Comment: I use a single file_get_contents call . It retrieves a lot of data tough, but still , it souldn't take so long . I'll try using cURL , thank you :)

Comment: Tried using cURL  , it takes about 7-8 seconds , which is still a lot , what am I able to do ?
I'm running the code on localhsot , xampp, apache , does it matter?

Comment: Maybe the remote server is responding too late. How fast is it when you visit the URL via your browser? It would be easier for us to help if you pasted the full code here.